# Resume from Suspend closes applications

Tags: suspend, laptop, power-management

Just loaded Ubuntu 15.10 on my old HP E1 Vision and am very pleased with it.  I have a minor issue in that if I Suspend using the power icon in the upper right corner of the screen, close the lid and then open later, the automatic resume loses all of the applications I had open.

This does not happen if I leave the lid open and resume with the power button on the console.  Also does not happen if I Suspend by closing the lid.  As I say this is minor and the work around is to avoid suspending with the power icon.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Create the file `/etc/acpi/local/lid.sh.post` and add the following to it:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -q closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
/usr/sbin/pm-suspend
fi
```

Make the file executable with `chmod +x lid.sh.post` and your problem should be solved.

Comment: @d.Fowler glad it did :) you should accept this answer by clicking on the grey tick just below this answer's downvote button :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my XPS 13 (9350) running Ubunutu 8.10. In some cases, it is an issue with drivers and hardware support.

I was able to resolve it by updating my kernel (Ubuntu):

`sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade linux-generic`

For more info and commands for other distros, see: https://www.linode.com/docs/platform/update-kernel/