# ubuntu 14.04 closes all programs upon awakening

Tags: suspend

When I open my laptop after it was closed it will open up with all programs closed and a window that says system program problem detected; if I report it I get told that there was an internal error and if I close it nothing happens. But, every time i close the laptop, this happens. I tried asking on Reddit but they were calling me an idiot and googling this problem has only shown me how to delete the crash reports (`rm /var/crash/*`).

Comment: May be you should try reinstalling Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693394/resume-from-suspend-closes-applications) to work for me.  I did it earlier today and it seems to be working for me (Ubuntu 16.04).

From the link:

> Create the file /etc/acpi/local/lid.sh.post and add the following to
>   it:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> grep -q closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state
> if [ $? = 0 ]
> then
> /usr/sbin/pm-suspend
> fi
> ```
>
> Make the file executable with chmod +x lid.sh.post and your problem
>   should be solved.