# All Applications Closing on Resuming from Sleep/Suspend

Tags: 17.10, suspend

I'm looking for a few pointers on where I can begin tracking down some anomalous behavior.

Occasionally (non-deterministically, but often enough to be inconvenient), I'll resume a session after suspending and all previously open applications have been closed.

This appears to have been an issue before with different versions:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2246309 [Solution no long applies as light-locker isn't installed]

[Resume from Suspend closes applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693394/resume-from-suspend-closes-applications) [ACPI based solution, non-deterministic behavior makes me suspicious as to whether this will work]

I'd like to reiterate that this doesn't always happen, and I haven't noticed any causal links (although I have a hunch that it may only happen if a lot of applications are open - perhaps the issue is memory related?).

I have noticed this in syslog though - I don't think it is related however, as this appears with every sleep:

```
systemd-sleep[23719]: Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
systemd-sleep[23720]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 255.
```

Any thoughts?